# Free group on a set B. If the free group is finitely generated, then B is finite.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Let B be a set. For simplicity, assume B contains all the formal inverses of its elements. Let W(B) be the set of words created from elements in B, and let F(B) be the set of equivalence classes [w] where w is a word in W(B). Any two words in the same equivalence class are related by a finite number reductions (insertions or deletions) by elements in B.

Here's my question: If F(B) is finitely generated, how do we prove that B is finite? In another problem I proved that F(B) is freely generated by the set of equivalence classes of elements arising from B; that is, equivalence classes of the form [b] where b is an element of B. Call this set S(B). My math prof. told me to use the universal extension property (where each map from S(B) to a group G extends to a unique homomorphism from F(B) to G), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Take the abelianization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume $F(B)$ is generated by the words $w_1,\dots,w_n$, and take the set of letters occuring in these words $w_i$.

Comment: So let me see if I got this right: Since we have finitely many words, there are finitely many letters. Each letter is an element of B. B is a subset of all these letters, for if there was an element of B outside this set of letters, then we'd have a word in F(B) that is not generated by w1,…,wn, a contradiction. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $ $

Comment: Awesome. Thank ya!